# Character set reverse search

Tags: linux, unicode, utf-8, charset

I have a set of strings (well, filenames, but that detail I can handle myself) that I want to convert to UTF-8. However, by trying the obvious candidates I'm not able to do the conversion successfully, except that it must be a 8-bit character set. So I'm asking, is there some kind of "reverse character set search" utility? I.e. I can provide as input that the character with decimal 138 should map to the unicode symbol "ä" (U+00E4), and the tool would spit out a list of character sets.

Comment: Do you know where the files come from (country, and operating system)?

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself, I sort of brute-forced it with something like

```
for c in $(convmv --list); do echo -n "$c: "; convmv -f $c -t utf8 SOMEFILENAME_WITH_NON_UTF8_CHARS 2>/dev/null; done
```

In this case it turned out the encoding was 'MacRoman', which apparently was some pre-OSX encoding used by Apple.